# Query failed with error code 59 and error message 'command not found' on MongoDB Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, studio3t, mongodb-cluster

I have a MongoDB cluster running MongoDB 3.4.14 in MongoDB Atlas. My application is successfully connected with this cluster and can read and write. I can connect with the shell to this cluster also.

When I try to connect with Studio3t (Version 2018.2.5) everything works fine as well. But when I try to view an available collection I get the following error:

```
Failed to retrieve documents

[somedatabase.somecollection@SomeCluster [replica set]] Database error!

Stacktrace: 
|_/ java.lang.Exception: [somedatabase.somecollection@SomeCluster [replica 
set]] Database error!
|____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 59 and error message 'command not found' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-*****.mongodb.net:27017
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the cluster configuration or with Studio3t itself. 
If I can provide you with more information that would help to solve the problem just let me know.

Comment: It's a Studio 3t problem surely. Most Atlas cluster nodes will actually be on MongoDB 3.6 ( including most existing nodes, unless you specifically opted to keep a version. I believe ), so if your cluster nodes are indeed that version, then it's very likely that other software has not updated the supporting driver, and most importantly removed deprecated methods. Your best general diagnosis anyway is to simply attempt connection from the plain old `mongo` shell. If you don't see any problems there, then it's definitely an issue with other software.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm currently not able to upgrade to MongoDB 3.6 since I'm using a free cluster. I guess I have to search for an alternative to connect to my database.

Comment: I'm actually saying the "opposite". The FREE services will actually be **MongoDB 3.6**. Older software may be happy with older versions, but various things in API have been removed from support in the 3.6 version. But it's the same conclusion. And as for "search", MongoDB has the client itself. Why you all seem to think you need a GUI in order to do anything surprises me on a regular basis. Just run a shell and copy/paste from your favorite editor.

Comment: Currently the only free cluster in Atlas runs version 3.4 sadly. I also tried to connect to the cluster with MongoDB Compass but this does not even connect.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Looks like there is an incompatibility with Studio 3T and Mongo 3.4 now. You can try MongoDB Compass Community edition and see if it fits your needs. It seems to work with 3.4.

Comment: @nopuck4you New Atlas deployments on the free/shared tier should now be 3.6. Existing 3.4 deployments have not been upgraded yet, but that will happen soon (with communication to the Atlas account owners). If you are having trouble connecting with the `mongo` shell or Compass, please create an [Atlas support issue](https://cloud.mongodb.com/support). If you can't connect with a third party tool like Studio 3T, you should contact the vendor for support.